# ERROR TypeError: makeStore is not a function

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, next.js

**Describe error**

I create a store by redux and put it into `_app.js` in next but it has error:

**Code**

```js
const theme = responsiveFontSizes(createMuiTheme());

const initStore = createStore(
  Reducers,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
);

const _App = withRedux(initStore)(
  class _App extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
      let pageProps = {};
      if (Component.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
      }

      return { pageProps };
    }

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fonts();
      const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");
      if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode) {
        jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
      }
    }

    render() {
      const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;

      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Head>
            <title>Doctor Finder</title>
            <meta
              name="viewport"
              content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
            />
          </Head>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
            <CssBaseline />
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Provider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
);

export default _App;
```

**Error**

> /!\ You are using legacy implementaion. Please update your code: use
> createWrapper() and wrapper.withRedux().

*TypeError: makeStore is not a function*

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the withRedux api is but based on the error it seems it's expecting a function but you are passing an object to it (initStore).

Try change initStore to something like this:

```
const initStore = () => createStore(
  Reducers,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
);
```